# Write text into first lines of every file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I want my web application to be free software, with a GNU license. I've read that I should add my name and the license in every file. I have a lot of files, so I guess that I could execute a command to write those lines to all the files. I've been looking around and found the `sed` command to insert text. So I'd do:

```
sed -i '1 i\/* Copyright 2013 Manolo Salsas  \nThis program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as published by the Free Software Foundation.\n\nThis program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more details.\n\nYou should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA*/ ' ./*
```

but this command isn't recursive, so I should do:

```
find ./* -type f | xargs sed -i '1 i\/* Copyright 2013 Manolo Salsas  \nThis program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as published by the Free Software Foundation.\n\nThis program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more details.\n\nYou should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA*/ '
```

It should insert those lines into the first lines of every file (expect hidden ones that begin with a dot), but it's not working.

**What could I be doing wrong?**

**Should I really add this lines to EVERY file?**

Comment: What does *not working* mean? What happens if you execute the second command? Does the first command work as expected? Which OS are you using?

Comment: See also the FSF FAQ on "Why should I put a license notice in each source file": https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#NoticeInSourceFile, and also in the GPL license itself: "It is safest to attach them to the start of each source file to most effectively state the exclusion of warranty" (in "How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs", near the end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution works (copied and pasted into my shell), except that it also touches dotfiles in subdirectories. To avoid touching those, you need to invoke `find` as

```
find -type f \! -name '.*' | xargs sed -i '1 i\/* ... */'
```

(`-and` is assumed between `-type f` and `\! -name '.*'`). Note that I need to escape `!` in my shell (Bash).

Note that the `insert` option of `sed`  doesn't work if the files are blank. If you write some text in the current folder's files, it works.

Apart from the configuration files, you should avoid writing to images. My guess is that it would be better to specify the formats to be written. Something like this:

```
find ./* -regex ".*\.\(php\|js\|txt\|html\|css\|yml\|twig\)" -type f | xargs sed -i '1 i\/* CCCopyright 2013 Manolo Salsas  [B\nThis program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as published by the Free Software Foundation.\n\nThis program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more details.\n\nYou should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA*/ '
```

**Update:**

Another solution to filter files based on file types is to use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)'s file type selection feature. Assuming, for instance, you'd want to select C and Perl files only:

```
ack -f --type=cc --type=perl | xargs sed -i '1 i\/* ... */'
```

(`type=cc` stands for C)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: There is an other issue. If you have images in that folder, those images will breake. You should include the desired formats to be written.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas Please don't put questions into answers. Whether or not you should add this line to every file depends on what the license requires. Usually it should go in every text-based source file.

Comment: @slhck - Thank you very much. I'll take into account.

Comment: @Raystafarian The "garble" you edited out is the license the OP needs to add to every file. Please don't remove it.

Comment: Yes @ManoloSalsas, you are right about the empty file problem. But that wasn't mentioned in the original question. I see it's been added to the answer now ;-) If I can think of a solution, I'll update the answer.